# How to observe cancellation token?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any other way how to observe cancellation token besides checking it in loop ?

```
while (moreToDo)
{
    // Poll on this property if you have to do
    // other cleanup before throwing.
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Clean up here, then...
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
     }

}
```

Example from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

I want cancel task when method is running more then 5seconds. But processing VeryLong method can takes more then 5 seconds.

```
var cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
Task.Factory.StartNew(
     () =>
     {
         VeryLongMethod();

      }, cancelationTokenSource.Token
);
```

As I was suggested I tryed register callback, but after timeout, the very long method was still executed.

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(20000);

        await Task.Factory.StartNew
        (
            () =>
            {
                using (cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() =>
                {

                    Program.Console.WriteToConsole("Failed on timeout.");


                    try
                    {
                        cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Action was processed already");                            
                    }

                }))
                {
                    VeryLongMethod();
                }
            }, cancellationTokenSource.Token
        );
```

Comment: Well, sure.  You can also check it outside a loop.  It's unclear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: if i remember correctly, `AggregateException` will be thrown if you cancel a task.. not sure what is your use case.. so cant say this approach is a good suggestion..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task event or action on cancel token requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903487/task-event-or-action-on-cancel-token-requested)

Comment: updated question

Comment: You can cancel the task after 5 seconds assuming the "veryLongMethod()" is some sort of repetitive task and you are checking for "IsCancellationRequested" repeatedly. 
If not, say your "veryLongMethod()" is reading a large text file, so even if you cancel the cancellation token, the task will not stop as it is not checking for this status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. Pooling periodically is the only way we can ever check if a task is intended to be cancelled. `CancellationToken` doesn't provides any other means of notification to check for it, `IsCancellationRequested` and `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` being the only ways we can ever know we must cancel.

That implies that with the current async-await task-based design, cancellable methods must periodically check on themselves if the caller wants to cancel, and provide an exit point themselves. There is no direct way of cancelling a method without changing it to "cooperate" with the cancellation system right now.

It doesn't needs a loop in itself, but some form of pooling is needed for the check anyway. A loop is a typical construct, but anything else can be used.

Comment: That's not quite correct, see the duplicate question I linked.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a callback which will be called when the token is cancelled:

```
using(var reg = cancellationToken.Register(() => { /* cancellation logic */ }))
{
    // your code
}
```

**Update:** To your updated question, you can tell a cancellation token source that it must cancel its token after a period of time, like this:

```
cancelationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Comment: Hi. I update my question about solution you proposed. Can you please have a look at it ?

Comment: okay, but how do you cancel your VeryLongMethod() exactly? You are not passing the token for it, you have to do something with it, it wont be cancelled automatically.

Comment: I understand now.