# Wait for all work items to complete before exiting when a request for cancellation is received

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore, cancellation

I have a loop that dispatches work items to multiple threads. The number of concurrent threads is limited through a semaphore. The loop should exit when a request for cancellation is signaled. However it should wait until all currently running threads have completed their work before exiting.

How would I best do this? Do I need to introduce another synchronization primitive and if so, which would be best suited here? Or is there perhaps even a way to do this with only the existing semaphore?

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp10 {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var t = new Thread(Loop);
            t.Start(cts.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to cancel.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelling loop");
            cts.Cancel();
            t.Join();
            Console.WriteLine("At this point all worker threads must have exited.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Loop(object state) {
            var ct = (CancellationToken)state;
            var numMaxThreads = 4;
            var sema = new SemaphoreSlim(numMaxThreads);
            try {
                while (true) {
                    sema.Wait(ct);
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
                        try {
                            Work();
                        } finally {
                            sema.Release();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
                // Block until all currently running work items have been
                // completed before continuing.
            }
        }

        static void Work() {
            var r = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
            Console.WriteLine($"  {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: Starting");
            var until = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(1000 + r.Next(5000));
            while (true) {
                var left = until.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
                if (left <= TimeSpan.Zero)
                    break;
                Console.WriteLine($"  {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: " +
                    $"Working, Left: {left}");
                Thread.Sleep(250 + r.Next(100) * 10);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"  {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: Ending");
        }
    }
}
```

PS. I would like to avoid using Tasks or the Tasks Parallel Library.

Comment: You can finish unfinished tasks by registering them - they will be executed after occurence of cancel event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32903578/12262729

Comment: @BartłomiejStasiak Thanks but I am not sure I understand. How would I use that to block my thread until all of the worker threads have completed?

Comment: By adding `ct.Register(() => Work())` under line `var ct = ...`. Wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is there perhaps even a way to do this with only the existing semaphore?

This. You can just `Wait` the semaphore as many times as the `numMaxThreads`:

```
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numMaxThreads; i++) sema.Wait();
}
```

> PS. I would like to avoid using Tasks or the Tasks Parallel Library.

I don't know why you want to avoid the [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl). Basically what you are trying to do is to invent the [`Parallel.While`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-parallel-while-with-parallel-foreach/) method. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671771/whats-the-best-way-of-achieving-a-parallel-infinite-loop/72750082#72750082) a modern implementation, based on the [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for). The advantage of using the TPL is that you get automatic termination of the loop in case of an error, and proper propagation of all errors bundled in an `AggregateException`. The TPL uses also the current thread as a worker thread, so you don't waste a thread just to control the other threads. In case you want to free the current thread, because it has to do work like `Console.ReadKey()`, you can offload the whole loop to the `ThreadPool` with `Task t = Task.Run(() => Parallel.For(/*...*/));`. The `Parallel` APIs support cancellation with the [`ParallelOptions.CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.cancellationtoken) property.